# I want a function that will decrement a value automatically everyday

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm working on an web application using NodeJS and MongoDB/Mongoose, and I want to create a method that everyday, at some hour, will automatically decrement a value from a field by 1.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` If you just want to run it every day at the same time.

```
setInterval(() => {
  // your code
}, 86400000);
```

where `86400000` is the amount of milliseconds in a day.

If you want more control over the timing, I recommend using [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

And of course your program needs to run on a server for it to run forever. Or you could leave your computer on forever, but that wouldn't be quite ideal.